# cmd.Parameters.Value not using type

Tags: npgsql

Hi With version 6 of npgsql, a command like cmd.Parameters[i].Value = value requires that value is a variable of the same type as previous cmd.Parameters.Add(name, type)
Another way to explain it; in
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(keycol, NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Bigint, keyid);
keyid must be of type bigint, can't be a string, even it is a compatible bigint like "12454"

This was not the case in version 3, where you were able to add all parameters like this
cmd.Parameters[i].Value = string, regardless type inside type, of course supposing it's compatible.

This makes code less simple as you have to test each type and use an according vaiable to insert

```
switch (champ.NpgType) {
case NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer:
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter<Int32>(champ.Column, champ.NpgType) { TypedValue = Convert.ToInt32(champ.Value) });
break;
case NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Bigint:
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter<Int64>(champ.Column, champ.NpgType) { TypedValue = Convert.ToInt64(champ.Value)});
break;
case NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Boolean:
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter<Boolean>(champ.Column, champ.NpgType) { TypedValue = Convert.ToBoolean(champ.Value) });
break;
case NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Double:
case NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Numeric:
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter<Double>(champ.Column, champ.NpgType) { TypedValue = Convert.ToDouble(champ.Value) });
break;
case NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp:
case NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date:
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter<DateTime>(champ.Column, champ.NpgType) { TypedValue = Convert.ToDateTime(champ.Value) });
break;
default:
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter<String>(champ.Column, champ.NpgType) { TypedValue = champ.Value });
break;
}
```

Am I right ?
Is there a more simple way to do that ? Why version 6 does not behave like version 3

Thanks

Olivier

Answer (score 0):

This is by-design: Npgsql takes a strongly-typed approach to data, and will not perform implicit conversions for you (e.g. string to int). Doing so can make it easy to accidentally write incorrect data or unintentionally perform conversions which are costly in terms of performance. Just like C# doesn't allow assigning a string to an int, Npgsql doesn't allow sending a string as an int.

Older versions of Npgsql may have been more lax on this kind of this, that's possible.